# Rotate Title Page

Tags: titles, rotating

I have a document that uses a landscape format. However, I can't figure out how to rotate my title page so that it fits with the rest of the text. Right now the title page is lying on its side.

I'm using the following code to make the title page. Can someone help me rotate it properly?

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, openany, svgnames, xcolor]{book}

\usepackage[landscape, twocolumn, left=1in, top=1in, right=1in, bottom=1in]{geometry}


\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\MakeOuterQuote{"}

\usepackage{lscape}

\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{pifont}
%%%%%%%%%% Experiments %%%%%%%%%%%%

\graphicspath{{Chapters/images/}{Chapters/images/Buttons/}}
\newfontfamily\signaturefont{Signerica Fat}

\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage{dashrule}


%%%%%%% Wallpaper

\usepackage{wallpaper}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%





\setromanfont[Scale=1.2]{Alegreya} 
\setsansfont{Alegreya} 
\setmonofont{Alegreya} 
\usepackage{setspace}
\linespread{1.5}



\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyfoot[C]{\{ \thepage \}}
\pagestyle{plain}




\setlength{\columnsep}{1cm}

%%%%%%% >> Button Images in TOC
\usepackage{titletoc}
\newcounter{mysecimage}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\stdsectioninToC{
\titlecontents{section}
  [3.8em]
  {}
  {\contentslabel{2.3em}}
  {\hspace*{-2.3em}}
  {\titlerule*[1em]{.}\contentspage}
}
\newcommand\iconsectioninToC{
\titlecontents{section}
  [3.8em]
  {}
  {\contentslabel{2.3em}%
    \stepcounter{mysecimage}%
    \smash{\includegraphics[height=17pt]{image-\the\value{mysecimage}}}\hspace{0.5em}% change here 
  }
  {\hspace*{-2.3em}}
  {\titlerule*[1em]{.}\contentspage}
}
\AtBeginDocument{\stdsectioninToC}
\makeatother


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{color, graphicx, wrapfig}

\newcommand*{\plogo}{\fbox{$\mathcal{PL}$}} % Generic publisher logo
\definecolor{Ahrenge}{RGB}{228, 132, 64}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
  colorlinks,
  linkcolor=black,
  urlcolor=Ahrenge}


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   TITLE PAGE
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


\newcommand*{\rotrt}[1]{\rotatebox{90}{#1}} % Command to rotate right 90 degrees
\newcommand*{\rotlft}[1]{\rotatebox{-90}{#1}} % Command to rotate left 90 degrees

\newcommand*{\titleBC}{\begingroup % Create the command for including the title page in the document
\centering % Center all text

\def\CP{\textit{\Huge Fancy Title}} % Title

\settowidth{\unitlength}{\CP} % Set the width of the curly brackets to the width of the title
{\color{LightGoldenrod}\resizebox*{\unitlength}{\baselineskip}{\rotrt{$\}$}}} \\[\baselineskip] % Print top curly bracket
\textcolor{Sienna}{\CP} \\[\baselineskip] % Print title
{\color{RosyBrown}\large Your Organization} \\ % Tagline or further description
{\color{LightGoldenrod}\resizebox*{\unitlength}{\baselineskip}{\rotlft{$\}$}}} % Print bottom curly bracket

\vfill % Whitespace between the title and the author name

{\large{Your Name}}\\ % Author name

\vfill % Whitespace between the author name and the publisher logo

%\plogo\\[0.5\baselineskip] % Publisher logo
2014 % Year published

\endgroup}


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   BLANK DOCUMENT
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document} 


\pagestyle{empty} % Removes page numbers
\begin{landscape}
\titleBC % This command includes the title page
\end{landscape}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Test}
This is a test.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Get rid of the `landscape` environment and use `\onecolumn` for the title page (use `\twocolumn` afterwards to return to the two column format):

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, openany, svgnames, xcolor]{book}

\usepackage[landscape, twocolumn, left=1in, top=1in, right=1in, bottom=1in]{geometry}


\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\MakeOuterQuote{"}

\usepackage{lscape}

\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{pifont}
%%%%%%%%%% Experiments %%%%%%%%%%%%

\graphicspath{{Chapters/images/}{Chapters/images/Buttons/}}
%\newfontfamily\signaturefont{Signerica Fat}

\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage{dashrule}


%%%%%%% Wallpaper

\usepackage{wallpaper}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%





%\setromanfont[Scale=1.2]{Alegreya} 
%\setsansfont{Alegreya} 
%\setmonofont{Alegreya} 
\usepackage{setspace}
\linespread{1.5}



\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyfoot[C]{\{ \thepage \}}
\pagestyle{plain}




\setlength{\columnsep}{1cm}

%%%%%%% >> Button Images in TOC
\usepackage{titletoc}
\newcounter{mysecimage}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\stdsectioninToC{
\titlecontents{section}
  [3.8em]
  {}
  {\contentslabel{2.3em}}
  {\hspace*{-2.3em}}
  {\titlerule*[1em]{.}\contentspage}
}
\newcommand\iconsectioninToC{
\titlecontents{section}
  [3.8em]
  {}
  {\contentslabel{2.3em}%
    \stepcounter{mysecimage}%
    \smash{\includegraphics[height=17pt]{image-\the\value{mysecimage}}}\hspace{0.5em}% change here 
  }
  {\hspace*{-2.3em}}
  {\titlerule*[1em]{.}\contentspage}
}
\AtBeginDocument{\stdsectioninToC}
\makeatother


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{color, graphicx, wrapfig}

\newcommand*{\plogo}{\fbox{$\mathcal{PL}$}} % Generic publisher logo
\definecolor{Ahrenge}{RGB}{228, 132, 64}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
  colorlinks,
  linkcolor=black,
  urlcolor=Ahrenge}


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   TITLE PAGE
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


\newcommand*{\rotrt}[1]{\rotatebox{90}{#1}} % Command to rotate right 90 degrees
\newcommand*{\rotlft}[1]{\rotatebox{-90}{#1}} % Command to rotate left 90 degrees

\newcommand*{\titleBC}{\begingroup % Create the command for including the title page in the document
\onecolumn
\centering % Center all text

\def\CP{\textit{\Huge Fancy Title}} % Title

\settowidth{\unitlength}{\CP} % Set the width of the curly brackets to the width of the title
{\color{LightGoldenrod}\resizebox*{\unitlength}{\baselineskip}{\rotrt{$\}$}}} \\[\baselineskip] % Print top curly bracket
\textcolor{Sienna}{\CP} \\[\baselineskip] % Print title
{\color{RosyBrown}\large Your Organization} \\ % Tagline or further description
{\color{LightGoldenrod}\resizebox*{\unitlength}{\baselineskip}{\rotlft{$\}$}}} % Print bottom curly bracket

\vfill % Whitespace between the title and the author name

{\large{Your Name}}\\ % Author name

\vfill % Whitespace between the author name and the publisher logo

%\plogo\\[0.5\baselineskip] % Publisher logo
2014 % Year published
\par
\endgroup
\twocolumn
}


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   BLANK DOCUMENT
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document} 

\pagestyle{empty} % Removes page numbers
\titleBC % This command includes the title page

\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Test}
\lipsum[4]
This is a test.

\end{document}
```

[image]

I commented out the font lines, since I don't have those fonts installed.